# innerHTML textbox after type text it not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, innerhtml

i having a issue, after when i type something on the textbox my texbox innerHTML is not working anymore (just for textbox), another divs that are still working.

this link is the example:
[Sample code Please help](http://codepen.io/YSLee/pen/dbuLr)

Any solution to fix this issue? or any other similar code that can be replace with this?

Comment: you want to insert value in text box??

Comment: there aren't any innerhtml for text box we have only values.So ask your question clearly.

Comment: Why do you use native javascript methods and properties when you have included jQuery? Use `jQuery.html()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is example...

Give value to any text box we use `.value` insted of `.innerHTML`.

```
        <body onload="myFunction()">        
         <input type="text" id="f6" value="5000" />
         <input type="text" id="G6" value="" />
         <button >Try it</button>        

        <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
          var F6=document.getElementById("f6").value;
          document.getElementById("G6").value = F6;       
        }
        </script>       
        </body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Prateek! Now i know it is value.. TQ TQVM!

Answer (score 0):

it's easy by using jQuery :

```
$(function(){
 var index = 1;
 $('#up').click(function(event){
   index++;
   if(index ==7 ){
   index = 1;
   }
 $('#greetingtlt').text('Text '+index);
 $('#textarea').text(index+'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.');
 });
     $('#down').click(function(event){
   index--;
   if(index ==0 ){
   index = 6;
   }
 $('#greetingtlt').text('Text '+index);
 $('#textarea').text(index+'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.');
 });
```

});

add ids to img controls :

```
 <img src="images/prevbtn.jpg" id="up" width="12" height="18">

<img src="images/nextbtn.jpg" id="down" width="12" height="18">
```